# Object class members as pointers to avoid #include in headers - is it good practice?

Tags: class, pointers, include, header-files, forward-declaration

This is really a question of precedence: which is more preferred in C++, avoiding pointers or avoiding #includes in header files?

### "Don't Use #include in header files."

There seems to be some ambiguity based on my research. In this SO question, the top answer says "...make sure you actually need an include, [don't use one] when a forward declaration or even leaving it out completely will do." (From [Header files and include best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420891/header-files-and-include-best-practice))

And this article explains the negative effect excess header inclusions can have on compile-time: http://blog.knatten.org/2012/11/09/another-reason-to-avoid-includes-in-headers/

As well as this tutorial, stating, "...you should try to put all of your code in the CPP class and only the class declaration in the HPP file.": https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Basic-Game-Engine#wiki-declarations

### "Don't Use Pointers."

But, there is also evidence that pointers should be avoided most often as well:

- [c++: when to use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658133/c-when-to-use-pointers)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56935/why-are-pointers-not-recommended-when-coding-with-c

### Which preference takes precedence?

If my understanding about avoiding #includes in header files is correct, this can easily be done by changing things like class members to pointers so I can use a forward declaration instead, but is this a good idea for class members whose lifetime only lasts as long as the class itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really an "one or the other". Both statements are true, but you need to understand the reasoning behind them.

**tl;dr:** Use forward declaration where possible to reduce compile time. Use stack objects or references as much as possible and pointers only in rare cases.

**"Don't Use #include in header files."**

This is a rather general statement, which as is, would be wrong. The more important part behind this statement actually is: "Use forward declarations **where ever possible**". Includes in header files are not something bad per se, but they often aren't needed either.

Forward declarations can be used, if the included type/class/etc. is used as a pointer in the new type/class/etc. declaration within the given header. Forward declaration just tells the compiler: "Somewhere a long the way you'll find the actual declaration of type X." The include can even be removed if the type isn't used at all in the declaration. The reason is that the compiler doesn't need to know anything about these types to calculate the required memory layout for the new type. For example a pointer has "always" the same size. Including the file additionally in the header, would potentially only waste processing power, since the compiler would have to open and parse the file, thus adding expensive seconds to the compile time. So in most cases you'll do yourself a favor by reducing the unnecessary includes in the header files and instead use forward declaration.

For the sake of completion: Forward declaration are explicitly needed if you get circular references (class A depends on class B, which depends on class C, which depends on class A). However this can often also reveal either bad design and/or old/outdate coding standards which would lead us to the second topic.

**"Don't use pointers."**

Again the statement is a tiny bit too general. One might rather want to say: "Don't use raw pointers."

With C++11 and soon C++1y the language itself has changed a lot. As much bad C++ books the world has seen, the more outdated C++ books float around nowadays (here's a [good list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) however). While in the past we were mostly stuck with pointers `new` and `delete` for memory management, we've evolved to better, more readable, less risk and 100% memory leak free ways to manage the data in memory. One of the magic words is RAII - since you linked something from SFML above, here's [a nice demonstration](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=9359.0) of the power of RAII. I see many people use pointers and `new` and `delete` just because or maybe because they are thinking in Java or C# terms were objects get instantiated with the `new` keyword. In C++ however object don't need to use `new` to be allocated and it's mostly preferable to run things on the stack instead of the heap. This works for many, many things, especially when using STL containers, which will hide the dynamic management in the background. The usage of the heap is mostly all cases only preferable if you need the data to be dynamic, non "local" or you need a lot of it. However when you use the heap, make sure to use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on the use case, but certainly not raw pointers. In modern C++ raw pointers should never own an object anymore. There are cases where it's okay to return a raw pointer to reference an object, but there's really no reason in modern C++ to call `new` on a raw pointer.

Lets get back to the original question though. The "Don't use raw pointers" is essentially more of a design question and quite unrelated to the whole header issue. While there might be some cases where you'll have to switch to raw pointers, due to circular references, the use of forward declarations is otherwise just about compilation time (and maybe clean code), but it's not as essential for the programming itself.

In short: Don't use raw pointers to avoid inclusions in header files, but use forward declaration where ever possible and utilize smart pointers as much as possible.